# Rebuilding SQL Indexes - When?

Tags: t-sql, indexing

When should one rebuild indexes? Nightly? Weekly? Hourly?

Comment: Just found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331236/sql-server-2005-how-often-should-you-rebuild-indexes

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the fragmentation levels not on the timeframe in general, check out the [Automated Index Defrag Script](http://sqlfool.com/2010/04/index-defrag-script-v4-0/) here by Michelle Ufford, it will check the fragmentation levels and only rebuild/reorg when needed

Answer (score 3):

Run an [intelligent script (from SQL Fool)](http://sqlfool.com/2010/04/index-defrag-script-v4-0/) , nightly say, and it will decide to do nothing, defrag or rebuild.

Basically, do the minimum commensurate with your fragmentation levels.

I would run it every night, personally, as a general rule. I'd rebuild stats every night at least.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the degree of fragmentation of Indexes.

If avg_fragmentation_in_percent value is > 5% and < = 30% then you should Reorganize Index.
If avg_fragmentation_in_percent value is > 30% then you should Rebuild Index.

Answer (score 0):

From SQL Server 2005 documentation :
    Execute ALTER INDEX ... REORGANIZE to defragment indexes that fall under the following fragmentation thresholds: (avg_page_space_used_in_percent < 75 and >60) or (avg_fragmentation_in_percent > 10 and <15)

Execute ALTER INDEX ... REBUILD to defragment indexes that fall under the following fragmentation thresholds: (avg_page_space_used_in_percent <60) or (avg_fragmentation_in_percent > 15)